# Working out associations in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to learn CakePHP, and attempting to replicate what I can do with standard PHP and MySQL with Cake.

I have an `event` table with event information, and a `list_items` table that holds entries for a bullet pointed list to be displayed on each event page. I also have a `venue` table that lists the venues (id, event_id and name) and finally an `instance` table which joins the event and venue together - this consists of id, event_id, venue_id, and date.

I have associated the tables how I think they should be:

```
class Event extends AppModel{

    public $hasMany = array(
        'ListItem',
            'Instance'
        );

}
```

bullet list items:

```
class ListItem extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Event'
    );

}
```

instances:

```
class Instance extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Event'
    );

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Venue'
    );
}
```

and venue:

```
class Venue extends AppModel{

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Instance'
);
```

and the Event controller has the query to find an event based on the ID:

```
public function view($id = null){
if (!$id){
throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Course'));
}

$event = $this->Event->findById($id);
if (!$event){
throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid event'));
}
$this->set('event',$event);

}
```

Are these associations correct? I want to be able to display the instance date alongside the venue - at the moment I can output the date no problem, but the venue eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because the recursiveness is not deep enough. To change that, you can do the following:

The easiest but poorest way, is to change the recursiveness before the find:

```
$this->Event->recursive = 2; //change it according to the deepness you want
```

This only will retrieve all the relationships according to the deepness assigned, but you can't exclude relations you will not need.

Or, the more advanced but richer way, add the `Containable` behavior and create the recursiveness by yourself. At the beginning of your model add the following behavior:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

and in your find function:

```
$event = $this->Event->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'ListItem',
        'Instance' => array(
            'Venue'
        )
    )
));
```

The advantage of `Contain` over `recursive` is that you can control every aspect of the relationships on `find` queries, so you can retrieve only the data you need. So it's **highly recommended** that you use `Containable` behavior

Please see the documentation for further info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: I'd give this +1 if it didn't even kind-of suggest using recursive.  Containable is the way to go by far.  I believe your answer will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I agree with you, but as eventually OP will cross with recursive in the future, it's safe to tell him all the options available to at least have knowledge of it. I'll edit my answer to remark more to use `containable` over `recursive`